# How to get string value inside a Mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I have this document stored in mongodb document:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("4eb7642ba899edcc31000001")
    "hash":"abcd123"
    "value":"some_text_here"
}
```

I am using NodeJS to access the database:

```
collection.findOne({'hash' : req.param('query') }, 
    function(err, result){ 
    console.log(res);   
});
```

The result of this query is the whole document, however I need to get only the "value" text: "some_text_here"

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the fields that you are interested in (_id will always be returned, though):

```
collection.findOne({'hash': req.param('query') },
                   {fields: ['value'] },
                   callbackFunction );
```

Comment: I tried this with Mongodb shell to check it out, however I just get a json object with just "_id" field on it.

Comment: The example was for the node.js driver. MongoDB shell has a different syntax: `findOne({hash: 'x'}, {value:1})` http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection

Answer (score 0):

You can do it such way:

```
collection.findOne({'hash' : req.param('query') }, 
    function(err, result){ 
        console.log(result.value);   
});
```

Comment: This query results the whole json document, I need something that will just output the field value I need. Is that possible?

Comment: No you cant. You will always recieve object with at least _id attribute. http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection

Comment: But you can get filter out everything else except _id and the one field you need.